# Calendar add days not working

Tags: java, calendar, cucumber

I have a method that puts random days in the calendar date to check some test been done in cucumber ...
here is the output of error ...

```
>  Background:                                                     #
> Accounts_accrue_interest.feature:8
>     Given Jim is a customer                                       # StepDefs.is_a_customer(String)
>     And Jim opens a savings account with account number 234       # StepDefs.opens_a_savings_account_with_account_number(String,long)
>     And the interest rate for a savings account is 2.25% per week # StepDefs.the_interest_rate_for_a_savings_account_it_per_week(String)
> diffL Fri Dec 16 16:32:46 GMT 2016 diffL Fri Dec 09 16:32:46 GMT 2016
> diffL -6
> 
>   Scenario: Account gets interest for one week  #
> Accounts_accrue_interest.feature:13
>     Given ú100.00 is deposited into account 234 # StepDefs.is_deposited_into_account(String,long)
>     When 7 days pass                            # StepDefs.days_pass(int)
>     Then 234 has a balance of ú102.25           # StepDefs.has_a_balance_of(long,String)
>       java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<102.25> but was:<100.0>
>         at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
>         at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
>         at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:553)
>         at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:683)
>         at my.bank.StepDefs.has_a_balance_of(StepDefs.java:118)
>         at ?.Then 234 has a balance of ú102.25(Accounts_accrue_interest.feature:16)
> 
> 
>   Background:                                                     #
> Accounts_accrue_interest.feature:8
>     Given Jim is a customer                                       # StepDefs.is_a_customer(String)
>     And Jim opens a savings account with account number 234       # StepDefs.opens_a_savings_account_with_account_number(String,long)
>     And the interest rate for a savings account is 2.25% per week # StepDefs.the_interest_rate_for_a_savings_account_it_per_week(String)
> diffL Thu Dec 15 16:32:46 GMT 2016 diffL Fri Dec 09 16:32:46 GMT 2016
> diffL -6
> 
>   Scenario: Account gets no interest for less than a week #
> Accounts_accrue_interest.feature:18
>     Given ú100.00 is deposited into account 234           # StepDefs.is_deposited_into_account(String,long)
>     When 6 days pass                                      # StepDefs.days_pass(int)
>     Then 234 has a balance of ú100.00                     # StepDefs.has_a_balance_of(long,String) @could
```

and here is what I am doing ...

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, arg1);
```

and calendar is

```
Calendar.getInstance();
```

now if you notice the ouput in the command line shows the same date for both times (diifL) it is the saem exact method running both time, except once with a paramete 7 and 2nd time with 6
but it always gives the difference 6

here is the difference code ..

```
  long diffDays = (account.getLastInterestDate().getTime()
.getTime() - curDate.getTime().getTime())
                / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

please help

Comment: Your method to calculate time deltas is crappy because it does not take into account possible daylight-saving changes.

Comment: Show code of `days_pass` method.

Comment: amh, ok ... Sorry not very familiar with Calendar and Stuff .. never did something that proficient but It is a good time to learn I guess ... if you could just show any example or point me out to some direction would be grateful

Comment: the days pass basically is that one line ... calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, arg1); and then i just call other methods from there